# Trying to update a Hibernate entity results in NonUniqueObjectionException

Tags: java, hibernate, set

I have a really difficult problem to diagnose. I'm scraping a web site for information and as part of that information I have a PersonEntity which has a set of Ethnicity entities (both of which have their own table). The relevant code is below:

**PersonEntity**

```
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = EthnicityEntity.class, mappedBy = "ethnicityId.person", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<EthnicityEntity> ethnicities;


public EthnicityEntity addEthnicity(EthnicityEntity ethnicityEntity)
    {
        getEthnicities().add(ethnicityEntity);
        return ethnicityEntity;
    }

    public Set<EthnicityEntity> getEthnicities()
    {
        if (ethnicities == null)
        {
            ethnicities = new HashSet<EthnicityEntity>();
        }
        return ethnicities;
    }
```

**EthnicityEntity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ETHNICITIES")
public class EthnicityEntity implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5459112416842302917L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private EthnicityId ethnicityId;
    // setters, getters, equals, hashcode
}
```

**EthnicityId**

```
@Embeddable
public class EthnicityId implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3596578582428917188L;

    @ManyToOne
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    @Index(name = "ETHNICITY_PERSON_ID_INDEX")
    @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID")
    @ForeignKey(name = "FKE1_PERSON_ID")
    private PersonEntity person;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "ETHNICITY", length = 40, nullable = false)
    private Ethnicity ethnicity;

    // getters, setters, equals, hashcode
}
```

**PersonDaoHibernate**

```
@Transactional
public String update(PersonEntity person)
{
    if (person == null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Person entity cannot be null.");
    }
    getHibernateTemplate().update(person);
    // This is where it fails ^^
    return person.getPersonId();
}
```

I also have some code that scrapes a page to get this data from a person's profile:

```
private void findEthnicities(PersonEntity person, String userName, Document document)
    {
        String ethnicities = findElement(userName, document, "dd[id=ethnicities").toLowerCase();    
        for(Ethnicity e : Ethnicity.values())
        {
            if(ethnicities.contains(e.getString().toLowerCase()))
            {
                EthnicityEntity ethnicity = new EthnicityEntity(new EthnicityId(person, e));
                person.addEthnicity(ethnicity);
            }
        }

    }
```

Currently what I'm doing is going through all my current users by a their age and trying to update (so I first get the person from my database then update any relevant fields that have changed). However, when I get to a certain user, I get an error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.anonymous.model.EthnicityEntity#com.anonymous.model.EthnicityId@ca737afe]
    at org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.checkUniqueness(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:638)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:305)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:685)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:677)
    at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$5.cascade(CascadingAction.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.cascadeOnUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:376)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultUpdateEventListener.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireUpdate(SessionImpl.java:742)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.update(SessionImpl.java:730)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.update(SessionImpl.java:722)
```

Through some debugging, I see that the Ethnicities set actually has two values in it, but each EthnicityEntity has the same value -- 'USERNAME' for the person and 'WHITE' for the ethnicity. They are identical. So, my first question is, how can this be so if this is a set? I imagine it might have to do with the fact that I'm adding an unattached entity (the one taken from scraping) to the set from the retrieved person (the attached entity), if that terminology is correct. However, this same code works for hundreds of other person with the same ethnicity (ie, "OTHER-USERNAME" and "WHITE"). Also, the actual value of "WHITE" is being taken from an Enum, so there's no issue with whitespace or something along those lines creating a value that appears the same but isn't.

Here's the part that's driving me crazy, it works if I run the code for just this user, and even more confusingly, even if I run it in a batch of around 30 users. It's only when it's a part of a much longer run that this happens. This too does not make sense since this is all I do to update multiple users:

```
   public void crawlCurrentUsers(int lowAge, int highAge) {
            if (highAge < lowAge) {
                return;
            }

            for (int i = lowAge; i <= highAge; i++) {
                List<String> personIds = personDao.getDistinctPersonIds(i);
                for (String personId : personIds) {
                    crawlUser(personId, true, true);
                }
            }
        }
```

Again, if I run crawlUser for just the user, it works. If I somehow restrict the users that are crawled to 30, it works. Is there some type of caching that might be getting out of sync or something along those lines in Hibernate? I'm really baffled here.

Additional debugging indicates that for all other users with just one ethnicity, in the findEthnicities method, after the person.addEthnicity(), the size remains one, as expected (since I was just adding an identical value to a set). However, when I reach this problem user, the size does in fact become 2 (but only if I run crawlCurrentUsers with a long enough range). I just don't know what to do and was wondering if anyone had some pointers or maybe some avenues to try and explore.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here may be that you are not defining a `hashCode` and `equals` method that use the `EthnicityEntity` id field.  Anything that goes into a `Set` needs to have those methods obviously.  Do they exist?   It looks like you want delegate those methods in `EthnicityEntity` to the same methods in `EthnicityId` and then define them there.

I'm a little confused by the `@ManyToOne` `Person` inside of the `EthnicityId` which is the `@EmbeddableId` for `EthnicityEntity`.  This to me seems like an overly confusing schema.  Although I think the missing methods is the issue, you may want to see if you can simplify your object hierarchy or use simpler generated ids and alternative indexes on your objects.

Comment: I actually do have those methods and they do delegate to the equals and hashCode in EthnicityEntity and EthnicityId. They're all Eclipse generated except that in EthnicityId, I use the person id off the person instead of the entire object (otherwise it'll get stuck in an infinite loop). So I don't think that would be the issue. I'll try remove parts until I can hopefully isolate it better.

Comment: I'm going to upvote this but I figured out the error and I'm making it my answer. Thanks for the input as it actually made me look a little closer at some things which led to me figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the site I was scraping from allows users to change user names. Being that I was scraping the site, I just figured I'd have to let them count as new people as there'd be no way to figure out who used to be who. However, I learned from my debugging that the link to the old profile name redirects to the new profile name. Unfortunately, I made the probably poor choice of using the username as the primary id for a person, so when inside the hashcode/equals of EthnicityId, it would be trying to do an update for USERNAME1 yet supplies person id values for USERNAME2.

This explains why the set was adding what seemed liked two identical values (they were, but the equals/hashcode were returning false). It also explains why running crawlUser by itself worked because, unbeknowst to me, I was using the user name of the renamed person, not the original person. If I try it by itself using the original person, it fails.

Phew, this was a pain! Guess it's bound to occur when I don't control the data I'm gathering.